# blender 3.5 no ANT landscape plugin?

Tags: add-on, blenderkit

i recently updated to blender 3.5 and ANT landscapes plugin is not showing

please help i am using fedora 37

[image: no ANT landscapes plugin]

[image: no ANT landscapes plugin]

Comment: I don't know in linux, but I can confirm the addon is availble on windows. Search for "landscape" in the addons.

Comment: Agree with @lemon in Windows. Note that searching for 'ant' will not find it as it's called 'A.N.T'! - It's found if you include the periods.

Comment: Mac confirmed :) This is one of the things that I never understood ... My vision of coder is precise/exact brained human, but in reality blender has a lot of addons with completely confusing naming (official name of addon, name in addon list, name in properties panel) ... this one is one of them ... I failed many times at the same point A.N.T. ... @lemon is saved he remember "Landscape" to search, lucky him :)

Comment: many plugins are missing in linux after update from 3.4 to 3.5

Answer (score 1):

I thought the exact same thing, tried a few different search terms, and then discovered that I had to type `A.N.T` in the search bar in order for the addon to appear in the panel.

[image: Screenshot of addon section]